# Get value from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting started with PHP and I have some troubles finding a way to output values from multiples arrays sent from an external site.

I did a foreach and the code that is printed looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Title 1
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [title] => Title 2
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [title] => Title 3
)
```

Any idea how I could get every id (1,2,3) in an echo?
Let me know if you need more informations!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try to use array_merge function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to echo all the id's in all the arrays, a simple solution would be:

```
foreach ([$array1, $array2, $array3] as $arr) {
    echo $arr['id'];
}
```

A better solution would probably to create one main array first:

```
$mainArray = [];
```

and every time you get a new array, you just push them to the main array:

```
$mainArray[] = $array1;
$mainArray[] = $array2;
// ... and so on
```

Then you'll have a multi dimensional array and can loop them with:

```
foreach ($mainArray as $arr) {
    echo $arr['id'];
}
```

Which solution that works best depends on how you get the arrays and how many they are.

**Note:** Using `array_merge()` as others have suggested will *not* work in this case, since all the arrays have the same keys. From the documentation on array_merge(): *"If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one."*

Comment: Thanks Magnus! The first solution did the trick. I will continue to explore and test your other options.

Comment: @JoeMecPak - Both solutions are basically the same thing. If you just have a few, fixed number of arrays, then the first should be good enough, since it won't require you to create an extra variable.

Answer (score 1):

As you can do:

```
$array = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
var_dump($newArray['id']);
echo implode(",", $newArray['id']);
```

A [demo code is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0940abf7ed07616eea8140d4ac4665cf16c96eb)